# Convert a date to timestamp in a join with interpolation

Tags: sql, timestamp, vertica

I have a table `a` in Vertica containing the `item_id` attached to a `code` at time `from_date`

```
create table a (
    code      varchar(16),
    item_id   int,
    from_date timestamptz
);
```

and a table `b` containing a `code` for a given date `t`

```
create table b (
    code    varchar(16),
    t       date
);
```

I need to retrieve the `a.item_id` from the `b.code` at the date `b.t`. The data looks like that :

```
insert into a values ('abc', 1, '2013-01-01 10:00:00 EST'::timestamptz);
insert into a values ('abc', 2, '2013-01-05 11:00:00 EST'::timestamptz);
insert into a values ('abc', 3, '2013-01-09 9:00:00 EST'::timestamptz);

insert into b values ('abc', '2013-01-06'::date);
```

I tried to use Vertica's [INTERPOLATE](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#15903.htm) in a LEFT JOIN in order to retrieve the previous `(code, item_id)` pair at time `t` with

```
select
    b.code, b.t, a.item_id
from  b
left join a on a.code = b.code and b.t INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE a.t;
```

This is giving me a type error `Interpolated predicates can accept arguments of the same type only`.

So I tried to convert `b.t` to a timestamptz

```
select
    b.code, b.t, a.item_id
from b
left join a on a.code = b.code
    and (b.t::timestamptz) INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE a.t;
```

This is giving me a syntax error `Syntax error at or near "INTERPOLATE"`.

Without INTERPOLATE, the SQL expression works but doesn't join on the previous row.

Is it possible to convert my date to a timestamptz in a JOIN with INTERPOLATE?

If not, is there any other approach that would allow me to retrieve the current `item_id` at time `t` ?

Comment: are you using MySQL, sql-server?

Comment: no, I'm using Vertica.

Comment: Vertica uses PostgreSQL, at least for syntax and datatype purposes. If you ever have a question about how certain datatypes work, searching on how it works with PostgreSQL almost always works for the same question in Vertica. Hope that helps in the future.

Comment: @geoffrobinson Unfortunately, the interpolated JOIN is specific to Vertica and the date to timestamp conversion is working without the interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hacky workaround by tricking the interpreter and do the date to timestamp conversion in a SELECT subquery:

```
select
    b.code, b.t, a.item_id
from b
left join (select a.t::date, a.code, a.item from a) a on a.code = b.code
    and b.t INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE a.t;
```

Comment: The date to timestamp conversion is a bug in Vertica. This workaround is the way to do the conversion right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.code, b.t, a.item_id
from b
left join a on a.code = b.code and b.t = cast(a.t as date);
```

But this solution might be wrong when there are more than 1 row in "a" table where t contains different times in the same date.

For example,

```
insert into a values ('abc', 4, '2013-01-06 8:00:00 EST'::timestamptz);
insert into a values ('abc', 5, '2013-01-06 9:00:00 EST'::timestamptz);
```

In that case you should decide which of this rows you need.
Say, you need latest row:

```
select b.code, b.t, a.item_id
from b
left join (
    select a1.code, a1.item_id, a2.dt
    from a a1
    inner join (
        select code, cast(t as date) dt, max(t) as max_t
        from a
        group by code, cast(t as date)
    ) a2 on a1.code = a2.code and a1.t = a2.max_t
) a on a.code = b.code and b.t = a.dt;
```

Solution may vary depending on your DBMS.

Comment: I need to join the '2013-01-06' date to the previous timestamp in the table `a`, i.e. '2013-01-05 11:00:00 EST', so using `=` won't work. That's why I need to interpolate the item_id for the date '2013-01-06' (I'm using Vertica).